# Type checking derived classes from collection of base classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, collections, derived-class, base-class

I have a couple of derived classes that are all from the same base class.

```
class Base {}
class ClassOne : Base {}
class ClassTwo : Base {}
class ClassThree : Base {}
```

Say I have an array of these class objects and I need to move through this array and perform specific operations depending on the derived class type.

```
Base[] objects;

foreach(Base entry in objects){
    //Check for class type to perform operations
}
```

I've looked at a couple of ways to handle this. At first I did try catch blocks then attempted to cast the objects caught the invalid cast then tried another cast. This seemed messy so I tried to do an if check.

```
if(entry.GetType() == ClassOne){}
else if(entry.GetType() == ClassTwo){}
```

But this doesn't work since they are all considered the Base type at that instance in the code.

What I have done to fix this for now is to add an enum with all the derived class types and set it in the constructors when the objects are created.

```
public enum DerivedClassType{
    Base,
    One,
    Two,
    Three
}
```

Now my foreach has a switch that can check that type before trying to cast.

```
Base[] objects;

foreach(Base entry in objects){
    switch(entry.derivedClassType){
        case DerivedClassType.One:
            ((One)entry).DoOneStuff();
            break;
        case DerivedClassType.Two:
            break;
        case DerivedClassType.Three:
            break;
    }
}
```

After going through all of these steps I want to know what the correct way to handle this type of issue is since this all seems much more convoluted than it probably should be.

Thanks

Comment: _"perform specific operations depending on the derived class type"_ - then you're using inheritance wrong. Please try to very explicitly explain (and not with contrived examples named base, one, two and three, but with your actual code) why you think you need this. In general it turns out you don't need this at all, and the need for it will go away.

Comment: add an overide method in each of these classes and make that method perform the different task. so it would be entry.method()

Comment: Have you tried `if(entry.GetType() == typeof(ClassOne))` or `if(entry is ClassOne)`?

Comment: Ok, I tried to make the example simple as to only ask the question I wanted answered. Let me see if I can be more explicit.

Comment: I have a base class called ObjectiveBase and it has functionality that all my objectives share. But I have varying types of objectives like ObjectiveZone, ObjectivePath, ObjectiveWatch. My code gathers all the objectives and stores them in a collection of ObjectiveBase objects. An ObjectivePath has a isEnd boolean that the other derived ones do not share. I check it in my loop when setting up a GUI for my user. Is this not the purpose of inheritance, to have a base with common behavior then derived with unique behaviour?

Comment: Sorry for this being convoluted. The way I was taught to use inheritance was illustrated with the mammals example(I do not know how common that is). But it basically is mammal is the base, it has things like walk, eat, drink, sleep, etc. Then you have something like Fox : Mammal {} and add something like burrow() that (in my example) a fax does but a Horse : Mammal {} does not. Does that mean that Mammal has abstract methods for everything every mammal could possibly use?

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to perform different operations depending on the class type is by using abstract methods.

```
abstract class Base
{
    public abstract void DoSomethingWithArg(string arg);
}

class ClassOne : Base
{
    public override void DoSomethingWithArg(string arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Class One says {arg}");
    }
}
class ClassTwo : Base
{
    public override void DoSomethingWithArg(string arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Class Two says {arg}");
    }
}
```

Then use it like this

```
Base[] objects;

foreach (Base entry in objects)
{
    entry.DoSomethingWithArg("Hello");
}
```

If you really want to continue down the path of your potentially unmaintainable code, you can implement it like this (requires C# 6);

```
foreach (Base entry in objects)
{
    switch (entry.GetType().Name)
    {
        case (nameof(ClassOne)):
            // Do something
            break;
        case (nameof(ClassTwo)):
            // Do something else
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Made this post in the wrong reply: Sorry for this being convoluted. The way I was taught to use inheritance was illustrated with the mammals example(I do not know how common that is). But it basically is mammal is the base, it has things like walk, eat, drink, sleep, etc. Then you have something like Fox : Mammal {} and add something like burrow() that (in my example) a fax does but a Horse : Mammal {} does not. Does that mean that Mammal has abstract methods for everything every mammal could possibly use?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Base[] collection;

foreach(var item in collection){
    if((item as TypeYouWhant) == item){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always add some explanation to your answers to improve their quality.

Answer (score 0):

@Massimiliano Girardi was corrent in pointing out the your punctual problem.  Simply replacing the Base with a var in your original loop allows you to extract the type information you need. You could have avoided going down the rabbit hole of the enum.

You were right in pointing out that a type hierarchy with overridden methods is not the answer to every problem.

You might consider a more functional approach which is more readable, testable, and I think maintainable than calling function methods in a switch statment or series of ifs.  I leave you with this solution (You can play with it here:https://repl.it/C59q/3):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Base {}
class ClassOne : Base {
    public void doOne(){
       Console.WriteLine("doing one") ;
    }
}

class ClassTwo : Base {
    public void doTwo(){
        Console.WriteLine("doing two");
    }

}
class ClassThree : Base {
    public void doThree(){
            Console.WriteLine("doing three");
        }
}


class MainClass {

  static Base[] objects = {
    new ClassOne(),
    new ClassTwo(),
    new ClassThree()

  };    

  public static void Main (string[] args) {

    Action<ClassOne> ClassOneFunc = delegate(ClassOne o)
         {o.doOne();}; 
    Action<ClassTwo> ClassTwoFunc = delegate(ClassTwo o)
         { o.doTwo();}; 
    Action<ClassThree> ClassThreeFunc = delegate(ClassThree o)
         { o.doThree();};   

    var contents = new Dictionary<System.Type, Action<dynamic>>
        {
            {typeof(ClassOne), ClassOneFunc}, 
            {typeof(ClassTwo), ClassTwoFunc},
            {typeof(ClassThree), ClassThreeFunc},

        };

    Action<dynamic> worker = o => contents[o.GetType()](o); 





  foreach(var each in objects){
    worker(each);

  }
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Robert, this seems like something I should know how to do in my normal C# workings. What exactly is this usage called? I want to know where I should look to learn more about what you are doing here. I don't however think that this works for what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'd call it using c# in a functional as opposed to OO style.